# res.redirect not redirecting and showing "Unable to Connect"

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I was making a NodeJS + ExpressJS Ecommerce Website. I am working on the admin panel of this website where a user can go to `/admin/products/new` where user will be provided with a form and when the user submits this form, the product will be created and the user will be redirected to `/admin/products` where all the products will be listed.

Here is the code snippet of the route handler:

```
    router.post(
      '/admin/products/new',
      upload.single('image'),
      [requireTitle, requirePrice],
      handleErrors(newProductTemplate),
      async (req, res) => {
        const image = req.file.buffer.toString('base64');
        const { title, price } = req.body;
        await productsRepo.create({ title, price, image });

       res.redirect('/admin/products');
   }
 );
```

res.redirect not redirecting and shows "Unable to Connect" but when I refresh the products is successfully created. Also there is no error in the console.

It is because when the products are created using `productsRepo.create()` they are created inside `products.json` file in the root directory. And because of that the nodemon is restarting the server due to the file changes and maybe that's the reason why `res.redirect()` is unable to reach the URL.

Comment: If you're seeing unable to connect, that means the server process has crashed. Check your console for any error logs, fix those errors and try again.

Comment: @Ananth There are no errors in the console that's why I am so confused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, actually as I said I knew exactly what the problem was i.e. the `nodemon` restarting the server due to the changes in `products.json` file and browser trying to access the `/admin/products` at the same time. So I researched a bit and found out that to prevent the `nodemon` from such behavior I have to tell it to stop checking for changes on files like `products.json`.

So I created a `nodemon.json` file inside the root directory and then adding the following to that file:

```
    {
     "ignore": "*.json",
    }
```